# What permissions should I set in Drupal core files?

Tags: 8, files

I get a very long message when flushing the caches, starting with

> Warning: unlink(/[my-website]/sites/default/files/css/css_mXyk_ET1j0oQS97qAccqHtOxn-21f8f9PeabB5s5OTE.css.gz): Permission denied in Drupal\Core\File\FileSystem->unlink() (line 114 of core/lib/Drupal/Core/File/FileSystem.php).

I never experienced such message with Drupal 7. It doesn't prevent the site to show up, but I wouldn't like to keep a messy installation.
Is it critical? What can I do?

Comment: It’s exactly the same as Drupal 7, your web server needs read and write permission over /sites/default/files

Comment: I set it to 755, it works. I was cautious not to change anything in case it needed protection.